# Java String Operations

Tags: java, string, amazon-s3

In a jsp form the user enter the report file URL i.e., 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf
or
cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf

But when the form is submitted, a java class(struts2 action) has to checks whether its a valid url by taking the  **cdn.gs.com**  as bucket name  and **/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf** as file path and then searches in the AWS s3 bucket.

For now we are getting the file_path from the url, but the cdn.gs.com is entered as a static variable before checking into S3.

Can we get the  **cdn.gs.com** as bucket_name(string variable) from the URL 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf
or
cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this, after looking into org.apache.commons.StringUtils.java class
Here is the code which solves my issue.

public boolean isValidReportURL(String url) {

```
    if (StringUtils.startsWith(url, "https://s3.amazonaws.com")) {
        bucketName = StringUtils.substringBetween(url, "com/", "/");
        filePath = StringUtils.substringAfter(url, bucketName).replaceFirst("/", "");

    } else {
        bucketName = StringUtils.split(url, "/")[0];
        filePath = (StringUtils.substringAfter(url, bucketName).replaceFirst("/", ""));
    }

    if (AWSFileUtil.doesFileExist(AWSConnectionUtil.getS3Object(null), bucketName,   
filePath)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

*url* variable can be

**https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf** or
**cdn.gs.com/live/reports/MVR_Q3_2009.pdf**